# Stackear productos dentro de una Lista

Tags: java, lista, arraylist, map, colecciones

espero que anden bien. Quería hacerles un consulta sobre el lenguaje de programación Java en particular con el tema "Colecciones" o Listas. La cuestión es que tengo que crear una Lista (ArrayList) que contenga dentro objetos de clase "Producto" *(int codigo, String nombre)* para luego estos pasarlos a un Map (K(Producto), V(cantProductos)), acá dejo lo que hice:

```
       List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<>();
   Map<Producto,Integer> mapnum = new HashMap<>();
   
   Producto p1 = new Producto(1,"coca");
   Producto p2 = new Producto(1,"coca");
   Producto p3 = new Producto(2,"te");
   
   productos.add(p1);
   productos.add(p2);
   productos.add(p3);
 
  
   
   for(Producto copy : productos){
       mapnum.put(copy, 1);
   }
   
    System.out.println(mapnum);
```

El tema es que cuando compilo estos no stackean, me imagino por que son distinto objeto por mas que ambos tengan el mismo contenido en sus atributos

[image: Lo que me compilo el código de arriba]

Lo que me gustaría saber es de que manera puedo hacer que estos que comparten el valor en sus atributos y que en vez de que estén separados hagan stack.Es decir, en este caso puse dos objetos de coca y me gustaria que estos se muestren en el Map como 1 y en cantidad sean 2.

Disculpen las molestias soy nuevo en Java y desde ya muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Entonces tu tienes ahora estos productos `{codigo: 1 , nombre: coca}` y `{codigo: 2, nombre: te}` que son los productos `p1` y `p3` de tu programa ahora lo que vas hacer es inicializar el mapa de productos ósea `mapnum.put(p1, 0)` (inicializas la cantidad de productos **coca** en 0) y `mapnum.put(p3, 0)` (inicializas la cantidad de productos t**e** en 0) ahora ya tienes 0 del producto **coca** y 0 del producto **te** en tu mapa `mapnum`, si deseas aumentar la cantidad de productos de coca a 5, recupera el producto `p1` del mapa y a continuación realiza `mapnum.put(p1, 5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo el código, en los comentarios la explicación de lineas agregadas:

```
       List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<>();
       Map<Producto,Integer> mapnum = new HashMap<>();
       
       Producto p1 = new Producto(1,"coca");
       Producto p2 = new Producto(1,"coca");
       Producto p3 = new Producto(2,"te");
       
       productos.add(p1);
       productos.add(p2);
       productos.add(p3);
       
       
       
       
       for(Producto copy : productos){
           
          for (Producto key : mapnum.keySet()) { //Se recorre los productos del map, si no contiene productos no pasa nada, no entra en el for, esto entrará en la segunda iteración
               if(key.getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(copy.getNombre())){ //Se valida que el nombre del producto a ingresar tenga coincidencia con el producto o los productos ya guardados
                  mapnum.put(key, mapnum.get(key)+1); //Si se encuentra un producto similar, actualiza la cantidad
               }else{
                  mapnum.put(copy, 1);//Si no encuentra el producto, se ingresa inicializando con 1
               }
          }


             if(mapnum.size()==0)  //Validamos la primera iteración para poner el primer producto
                mapnum.put(copy, 1);
       }
       
        
        for (Producto key : mapnum.keySet()) {
            System.out.printf("Nombre=" + key.getNombre()+ "   Cantidad=" +mapnum.get(key)+"\n");
        }
```

Saludos.

Comment: Justo lo que buscaba, muchas gracias Omar workeo!